# Crud operation in single stored procedure in c#

Tags: c#, sql

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.bicrudlogin 
    (
    @id int,
    @username nvarchar(50),
    @password nvarchar(50),
    @type varchar(50),
    @status varchar(50)
    )   
AS
if(@status='insert')
Begin   
insert into tbllogin  values(@username,@password,@type)
End

if(@status='select')
Begin   
select type from tbllogin where username=@username and password=@password
End

if(@status='update')
Begin   
update tbllogin set username=@username,password=@password,type=@type  where id=@id
End

if(@status='delete')
Begin   
delete from tbllogin where id=@id
End 

RETURN
```

and code for accessing data using stored procedure:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("bicrudregistration",con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",txtusername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",txtpassword.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status","select");

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

If this is wrong way, then tell me how to do it.

Rather than writing separate stored procedure for every operation.

Comment: Tag dbms used. (That doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all...)

Comment: What's wrong with having specialized queries?

Comment: MS SQL is used to do store procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow if this is production code then I really do worry however this is a very broad question and will try my best to answer. Usually, you would separate out your read and write concerns so for example:

```
public interface IGetUserQuery
{
    User Execute(string username, string password);
}

public class GetUserQuery : IGetUserQuery
{
    public User Execute(string username, string password)
    {
        // your code
    }
}

CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetUser (@username nvarchar(50),@password nvarchar(50))
AS
select type from tbllogin where username=@username and password=@password

public interface IAddUserCommand 
{
    void Execute(string username, string password, string type);
}

public class AddUserCommand : IAddUserCommand 
{
   public void Execute(string username, string password, string type)
   {
       // your code
   }
}

CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddUser (@username nvarchar(50),@password nvarchar(50),@type varchar(50),@status varchar(50))
AS
insert into tbllogin  values(@username,@password,@type)
```

This is an example of how to get a user. But why so granular? The simple answer is this allows you to unit test your code, i.e. `mock` what you are expecting from the query and drive the behavior of your software. Your stored procedures should be dumb and serve as a means of getting and dumping data. Logic what you have there should be placed in code. When it is situated in stored procedures this becomes more difficult to maintain and often causes greater problems as you don't know how many components, i.e. parts of your software are using that sproc. If you make a minor change you can impact several components. Through code you can find this out as you will get compilation errors if you change the contract. Also you would hope unit test coverage would also find issues.